# How to load a pkcs#11 library module from different path instead of loading from /usr/local/lib/

Tags: linux, pkcs#11

Lets say we installed our PKCS#11 project in one system successfully and library saved in '/usr/local/lib/'. 
Also it's working fine(able to load pkcs#11 lib module in applications).

Now how can we load the module in other system with the same library...!

Comment: which application do you want to load pkcs#11?

Comment: like email application-thunderbird for signing

Comment: You can define the path of Pkcs#11 lib in some application.  I don't use Thunderbird but in Firefox ,Adobe reader, outlook and etc you must define your module.

Comment: It's not neccesary loading a module in only thunderbird, even firefox also fine..Though i am specifying the path not able to load the module. Note: here i am considering only shared library and i am trying to load that...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/PKCS11/Module_Installation

Comment: Please consider adding an answer describing the way used to solve the problem (e.g. if it was solved by copying some more libraries (the pkcs#11 module depends on) to the other system). After some time, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: The problem is not solved yet. Sorry for the previous comment. Can't able to load a module with only shared library(not by installing)...

Comment: Maybe the installation changes load library paths. Try to use command `ldd /somewhere/yourPkcs11module.so` on the other system and check for lines containing `not found` (unresolved dependencies). You question provides so little information -- try to describe at least what exactly you did and what exactly went wrong (including error codes, messages...). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Able to load module successfully on the other system..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have taken the shared library of pkcs#11 module and also dependent library.

Checked the dependencies of shared library using command - 'ldd'

Based on result of 'ldd libpkcsmod.so', have installed required packages and copied dependent library to /usr/local/lib/.

Finally run the 'ldconfig' in order to create, update, and remove the necessary links and cache (for use by the run-time linker, ld.so) to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/usr/lib, /lib64 and /lib).

Finally able to load the pkcs#11 module in the applications like- Thunderbird, firefox e.t.c..